# Estimating the energy shift due to vacuum polarization in hydrogenic orbits

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

In his *Quantum Theory of Fields*, volume I, section 11.2, Weinberg gives an estimate of the shift of the energy levels of hydrogenic orbits due to vacuum polarization.

First he obtains the contribution to the potential:
\begin{equation}
\Delta V(r) = \frac{e_1 e_2}{(2\pi)^3}\int d^3 q \; e^{i \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{r}} \left[ \frac{\pi (\mathbf{q}^2)}{\mathbf{q}^2} \right] \tag{11.2.38}
\end{equation}

where $\pi({\mathbf q}^2)$ is the vacuum polarization:
\begin{equation}
\pi(q^2)=\frac{e^2}{2\pi^2} \int_0^1 dx \;x(1-x)\ln\left(1 + \frac{q^2 x(1-x)}{m^2}\right) \tag{11.2.22}
\end{equation}
then he expresses the energy shift as:
\begin{equation}
\Delta E = \int d^3 r \; \Delta V(\mathbf r) |\psi(\mathbf r)|^2 \tag{11.2.37}
\end{equation}
where $\psi(r)$ is the wave function.

Finally he writes:

> This perturbation falls off exponentially for $r\gg m^{-1}$. On the other hand, the wave function of electrons in ordinary atoms will be generally confined within a much larger radius $a\gg m^{-1}$; [...] The energy shift will then depend only on the behavior of the wave function for $r\ll a$. For orbital angular momentum $l$, the wave function behaves like $r^l$ for $r\ll a$, so Eq. (11.2.37) fives $\Delta E$ a proportiona to a factor $(ma)^{-(2l+1)}$.

My question is: how is this estimate obtained? Combining two expressions he gives a few paragraphs above I obtained (for $|\mathbf r| \neq 0$, $|\mathbf r|\ll 1$):
\begin{equation}
\int d^3q \;\pi({\mathbf q}^2)e^{i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}}
 = -\frac {2e^2}{r^3} \int_0^1 dx \; x(1-x) \left[ 1 + \frac{mr}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\right]
   \exp\left(\frac{-mr}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\right) \sim r^{-3}e^{-mr}
\end{equation}
so I suppose that, from (11.2.38):
\begin{equation}
\Delta V \sim r^{-1} e^{-mr}
\end{equation}
and finally from (11.2.37):
\begin{equation}
\Delta E \sim \int d^3 r \; r^{2l-1} e^{-mr} 
      \sim \int dr \; r^{2l+1} e^{-mr} \sim m^{-(2l+1)} e^{-ma} \sim m^{-(2l+1)}
\end{equation}
In the next to last step I integrated by parts to keep the term in the lowest order on $r$ (that is $r^0$).

Are the steps above correct? And if so, where does the additional $a^{-(2l+1)}$ come from?